# Detecting the connection is closing in a chat server written in Python 3

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, connection

Usually Python chat servers contain the following lines :

```
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data: break
```

where the connection `conn` was defined as :

```
conn, addr = s.accept()
```

It seems to me that when the connection is closing, the client sends an empty string to the server. Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct.

And now this answer is not too short anymore.

Answer (score 0):

On a blocking socket, recv() blocks until it can return at least one byte of data.  If the other end closes the socket, recv() returns an empty string (zero bytes of data).